# Another top-level WPF Window is stealing hotkeys/commands

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have a top-level WPF window with some standard WPF controls; one of them is TextBox. I instantiate my Window from VisualStudio extension, but I don't believe VS is one to blame for the following:

If I show my Window using ShowDialog(), everything works nicely.

However, I would like for my window not to be modal, so I use Show instead, which opens some problems:

1. In TextBox I can write characters. But, if a VS source editor is opened, it will steal clipboard hotkeys (ctrl+v, for example) and backspace will stop working.
2. If I press alt+f4, VS will exit, not only my window (which has focus at that moment).

Obviously VS is stealing keys and/or commands and I don't know how to prevent it while my non-modal Window has focus. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: I have never seen such an issue. Can you provide more information? Is there anything in particular that you are doing with this Window?

Comment: I've just managed to reproduce this with a simple Window with only a single <TextBox/>.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? Are you writing an extension for Visual Studio?

Comment: I create a new instance and call .Show(). And the described happens.

Comment: I have put an example project here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kza8uinij4ume4b/VSIXProject1.zip?dl=0

Please recompile and run. An experimental VS instance will launch. From the Tools menu execute 'Invoke Command1'. A non-modal Window with TextBox only will launch. It works correctly, except for alt+f4 which closes whole VS.

Now, open any project in VS and have at least one source editor active. You'll see that TextBox Window will stop responding to clipboard hotkeys, arrow keys, backspace, etc (but letters will work).

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a Visual Studio extension, I'd recommend to implement your non modal WPF window as a Visual Studio tool window. It should resolve these keyboard stealing problems.

Answer (score 0):

In meanwhile, I've managed to resolve my problem by putting my Window into a separate UI thread.

However, since I'm still learning WPF, I'd really like to know an explanation and real solution to the problem.